# Get publish directory in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I have an asp.net mvc application that I am publishing with Publish feature of Visual Studio and I have a custom MSBuild task that needs the directory that I am publishing to so it knows where to copy some custom build files to...
I've tried $(OutDir), $(PublishDirectory) and a bunch of others... how do I get this path?

Answer (score 15):

For me what worked was:

```
$(PublishUrl)
```

And i got what i was needing: My publish directory.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I've got the full path using: `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(PublishUrl)`

Answer (score 5):

I was able to combine $(ProjectDir) & $(PublishDir) to get the publishing folder. However, I was publishing SharePoint app but I think it should work for other cases as well.

For example to call a program

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectDir)\app.exe&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)$(PublishDir) &quot;"/>
```

Comment: When publishing to local folder, `$(PublishDir)` seems to evaluate to a temporary location. This might be useful when this value is needed while the build is in progress (e.g. for FTP upload). `$(PublishURL)` evaluates to the actual destination folder if anyone needs to know.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `PackageArchiveRootDir` property to resolve that. The default value for that is `obj\Debug\Package`. So if you need the full path you just combine the MSBuildProjectDirectory with the PackageArchiveRootDir like: `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(PackageArchiveRootDir)`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i am late to the party, but this post pops up when you search for.
What works for me, is what is posted [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/678)

```
<Target Name="MyCustomPrePublishTarget" AfterTargets="PrepareForPublish">
  <ItemGroup>
    <PublishDir Include="$(PublishDir)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Message Importance="High" Text="Absolute PublishDir is: %(PublishDir.FullPath)" />
</Target>
```